# how i can place my xml file in url in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing a XCAP application.In my application i am developing a xml file.Here my problem is this xml file,i want to place an url.can any one help to me?
thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

u can add the xml file to your app resources.

then use

> ```
> NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myXmlFile" ofType:@"xml"];
> //here is ur URL
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
> ```